# Android Listview From Database

Tags: android, sql, database

I'm new in android. I'm facing a problem creating a listview using data from sqlite database.
I found this code below to create a listview from contact data

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get a cursor with all people
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,CONTACT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                // Use a template that displays a text view
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                // Give the cursor to the list adatper
                c,
                // Map the NAME column in the people database to...
                new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                // The "text1" view defined in the XML template
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private static final String[] CONTACT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
}
```

Now I use this code to pull data from database

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
    String TableName = "myTable";
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

   // Get a cursor with all people
    Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);
```

Now How can I combine these two codes so I can show data pulled from a database in this list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the data from both sources (contact and DB), I think only option you have is construct an array with return values from both sources.

```
List finalList = new ArrayList();
 Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,CONTACT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
c.moveToFirst();
```

Iterate this cursor and populate the String value to finalList

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;
    String TableName = "myTable";
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

   // Get a cursor with all people
    Cursor c2 = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null);
   startManagingCursor(c2);
c2.moveToFirst();
```

Iterate c2 cursor and add values to finalList.

Convert finalList to array by Iterating finalList

```
String[] ipArray = new String[finalList.size()];
```

loop through list and populate the values to ipArray.

I don't have IDE handy, so I have typed the flow.

Comment: If that is the case just copy db code in your question and replace Cursor c=getcontentaresolver(...)..

Comment: I tried it before asking this question.But its showing error

here check the log file

http://polbd.com/log.txt

Comment: I had similar issue, instead of using simplecursoradaptor, I have used following mechanism.Cursor cur = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TableName , null); startManagingCursor(cur); List<String> makTempList = new ArrayList<String>(); if (cur.moveToFirst()) { do { int tempVal= cur.getInt(1); String tempValYear = String.valueOf(tempVal); if (!makTempList.contains(tempValYear)) { makTempList.add(tempValYear); } } while (cur.moveToNext()); }  Then convert list to array and pass this array as input parameter for list.

Answer (score 0):

If suppose you already have data in your cursor, you can follow code in the following tutorial

http://chetanandroidarora.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/customcursoradapter/